# Efficient and deterministic ranking items in collection?

Tags: c#, sql

I have list of billions of items in SQL which can be shuffled by user at random, by moving them inside list to another position, I consider using simple double divide solution:

```
Id,  Rank
1    10
2    20
3    30
4    40
5    50
```

Now user moves item id=3 to first position and I perform item rank recalculation based on their adjasent items (0 - means no relative from left, max - no relative from right):

```
Id,  Rank
3    (0+10)/2 = 5
1    10
2    20
4    40
5    50
```

Now there is a bug - until it reach epsilon for double, it will work, after that you will get a couple of elements with epsilon and they are not possible to move. 
This can be avoided by infrequent recalculation of stack rank for entire collection, but I hesitate at the moment to implement this, because this looks too much.

I wanted to know is there some other algorithmic solution other than changing billions of items or is there a well-known name to this problem to find appropriate solution myself.

Comment: Are you actually using some sort of indexing (clustered for instance) or is it jus the order of the items that matters? If the latter is the case, then you could have a pointer to the next number. Than means you need to update a couple of elements instead of one, but you never have to recalculate.

Comment: One method is to do the floating point method and periodically re-assign numbers to the values.  That said, I wonder if there is a better solution to the *actual* problem.  I don't see how users would be reordering *billion*s of rows.

Comment: There is something unclear. Why do you need that rank, because if it change each time you move an item, then it's meaningless to search by rank. Then what's the purpose of that rank? From what I can understand I would use a balanced tree and remove that rank.

Comment: I believe you will be able to solve this problem using double as a Rank instead of Int. There is an unlimited amount of values between 1 and 2: 1.0 < 1.1 < 1.2 < 1.21 < 1.21111 < ... < 1.9 < 2.0. So you always can "insert" another one value between two.

Comment: @VDN not unlimited, you can reach epsilon after aproximatelly 1000-2000 iterations - https://dotnetfiddle.net/zVxUnY, this is the bad case but ingeneric depths is a little bit obscure. Noceo - this is actually a good one! Thank you! I will consider this!

Comment: @eocron yes, you are right. My mistake.

Comment: @P.PICARD Rank is just a way to represent custom-order list. You can think of it like plain index in list:   mylist[0.234], with a little addition - it will be used ONLY for ORDER BY function.

Comment: What about using string as Rank?  Let's say item1.Rank = "1", item2.Rank = "2", so you can insert an item with Rank = "11" between them. And "1".CompareTo("11") = -1, "2".CompareTo("11") = 1. The cons is that it will have a great impact on performance, I think.

Comment: @VDN I ghought about that, but it is overkill for performance, yes. The problem is SQL is not supporting indexing for order other than std types, so this problem is probably solvable only through linked list.

Comment: The use cases are not detailed enough. When you change the position of an item, do you specify a relative or an absolute position? Or always at the begining or the end?

Comment: @P.PICARD the use case is simple - let users decide the order of items, and don't commit queries into SQL such as "here we go again, proceed to recalculation of custom order for them all, muhahah". As you see from Noceo answer, there can be just link to other element, no stack rank involved.

Comment: As 1 billion is huge and as you will have no other choice than to reindex regularly, you may think about defining pages of items, which concretely means having 2 ranks. The first being the rank of the page, the second being the rank of the item inside the page. Then you can do ORDER BY rank1, rank2 for instance. By doing so you will be able to reindex page by page and not the whole stuff all at once. Hope this helps.